# How can I redirect a log in a NetBeans application with auto-generated logging in the catch blocks?

Tags: java, logging, netbeans-8

The application I am working with has log calls in the `catch` blocks auto-generated by NetBeans only and no other kind of logging:

```
Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

What steps should be taken to redirect log output from the console to for example a text file?

I read Lars Vogel tutoriral http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html and for the most part understand what he is doing, but apparently when he wanted to log an event, he would call a method from an instance of his own logger `LOGGER`.

NetBeans developers probably intended to auto-generate the log calls the way they did for a reason. Does their logging have to be replaced as in the tutorial, or can it be simply configured to use another logging destination?

My confusion stems from the fact that `Logger.getLogger` is a static method.

Answer (score 0):

> What steps should be taken to redirect log output from the console to for example a text file?

From the [Java Logging Overview Examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a2.0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Handler fh = new FileHandler("%t/wombat.log");
    Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
    Logger.getLogger("com.wombat").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
    ...
}
```

That example creates a wombat.log file in the temp directory.

Otherwise you can modify or specify a [logging.properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) entry to install a FileHandler.  Here is a modified entry of the 'lib/logging.properties' located in your Java Home directory.

```
############################################################
#   Global properties
############################################################

# "handlers" specifies a comma separated list of log Handler 
# classes.  These handlers will be installed during VM startup.
# Note that these classes must be on the system classpath.
# By default we only configure a ConsoleHandler, which will only
# show messages at the INFO and above levels.
#
#handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# To also add the FileHandler, use the following line instead.
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

You can use the 'java.util.logging.config.file' system property on launch to specify alternate log configuration files.

> if getLogger() is a static method, which executes without an instance of Logger class being created,

Contained in the Java Logging Overview listed above there is a link to the [Java SE API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).  That is the contract for how all this works.

If you look up [Logger.getLogger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-) you'll see:

> Find or create a logger for a named subsystem. If a logger has already been created with the given name it is returned. Otherwise a new logger is created. 
>   If a new logger is created its log level will be configured based on the LogManager configuration and it will configured to also send logging output to its parent's Handlers. It will be registered in the LogManager global namespace.

The getLogger method is creating or locating a logger.

> than where does addHandler() persist its result?

Handlers are store on the logger instance.  The output type depends on the handler.  The properties of each handler are described in the API spec.

[The Logging Hierarchy and Record Forwarding](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/19/log.html?page=2) might help you understand what is happening in the example code.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not getting it: if `getLogger()` is a static method, which executes without an instance of `Logger` class being created, than where does `addHandler()` persist its result?

Comment: Don't I have to create an instance of a Logger class in the first example of the answer before assigning a handler to it? It seems that lines 3 and 4 refer to the different loggers? The names are different "" and "com.wombat".

Comment: Look up 'factory pattern java' in your favorite search engine.  Read the Logger.getParent documentation and then read the Logger.setUseParentHandlers(boolean) documentation.

Comment: Is the following not correct? The result of `addHandler()` cannot depend on the handler, as it is a method of `Logger`. In order for the handler to be accessible to multiple `getLogger()` calls, there has to be somewhere an instance of the `Logger` class storing the handler so added.

Comment: Handlers are properties of loggers.  Loggers are created or looked up by the LogManager.  Logger.getLogger asks LogManager to find or create a logger object.  LogRecords are published to parent handlers by default.  Therefore, using the default settings the root logger will see all LogRecords.